# MVC frameworks, should models resemble a 'module'-like structure?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm in the early stages of building a website using CodeIgniter, a PHP MVC framework. My models are, so far, fairly simple, yet I'm already doubting my coding approach. Is it a bad idea to let models use eachother? While it certainly reduces the amount of code needed, it also raises a strong dependency on outside code within each model method. Is this okay? Or does the methods need a more 'module' approach where they just work, independent of other methods?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: CodeIgniter is Passive-MVC. In the original scheme, models were supposed to represent business logic, not just database interfaces. So simplify your code, don't follow a [hypothetical pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549857/simple-php-mvc-framework/1549970#1549970). If the models depend on each other in the real world, so should the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, models should be grouped together into independent modules. You should then be able to move that module from CodeIgniter app to CodeIgniter app and it should work with little to no modification.

So it's OK for models to use each other. A model should represent a real-world object, and real-world objects rely on each other too!

Comment: You're contradicting yourself a bit - if a model should be able to move from app to app, it shouldn't have other model dependencies. If a model is dependant on another model, and you move the one which requires the dependency, it'll just break.

Comment: @xil3: No, you're misreading what I said. I said models grouped into modules, and the modules can be moved.

Answer (score 1):

Yea There is 2 ways to do it how ever,

There is the model call (Instantiate) the new object its self

Or you can have your controller call (Instantiate) the object and pass it to your model

ether works but my personal preference to do the first